# SQLite, Python - параметризация запроса

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

у меня есть запрос вида:

```
sql = """
UPDATE cats
SET ? = ? 
WHERE id =?
"""
cur.execute(sql, [(gid),(sms),(per)])
```

Моя цель-внедрить нужную колонку, а в неё нужное значение, я попробовал поставить `?` после `SET`, но на это получил:

> `Exception has occurred: OperationalError near "?": syntax error`

Ага, дело в синтаксисе, но тогда как? Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать, ведь мне надо каждый раз вставлять разные значения в РАЗНЫЕ колонки?

Comment: можно просто формировать запрос на `update` динамически, вставляю в него нужную колонку

Answer (score 1):

В SQL запросах параметризировать можно только [литералы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Параметризировать наименования таблиц, столбцов, индексов, тригеров и т.д. нельзя. Для этого можно динамически составить SQL.

```
sql = """
UPDATE cats
SET {col_name} = ? 
WHERE id =?
"""

parms = (sms, per)

cur.execute(sql.format(col_name="gid"), parms)
```

Comment: опередили на пару секунд =)

Comment: @Viktorov, oops, не знал что вы тоже пишете ответ...

Comment: ну в этом нет никакой проблемы. ваш ответ подробнее и со ссылкой на вики.  Я на вопросы смотрю, как на возможность научится чему то новому, так как в питоне я новичок. Ответ лучше чем мой позволяет мне узнать еще больше. Так что я только рад)